# Android access to front camera on HTC Thunderbolt

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, htc-thunderbolt

I need to access the front camera on the HTC Thunderbolt from within an application (as a standard Camera object).

Can any developers point me in the right direction? HTC has released a jar for accessing the front camera on the EVO, but it doesn't work when I compile against that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify camera.Open(0) or camera.Open(1) for front or back camera?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)